# Apply PLSDA model to predict another data?

Tags: r, linear-discriminant, pls

I am developing a discriminant model using PLSDA (mixOmics package, the model works well by external validations. To do external validation, I use the predict() function. However, suppose now I have to give this prediction equation/model to my partner then how should that work? 
In a simple partial least square regression, we have an option to extract coefficients, but with plsda I could not see. 
Can you give me some advice about this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`predict.plsda` predicts the class using a distance measure. You can see it in the outout's `$class` entry.
Hope it helps.